# Does ChartJS Annotations render Line annotations on X-axis index?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

**Problem Description:**
I'm working on a project where I need to render a vertical line through a dataset to indicate a break-even point on a chart. The x-axis labels are dynamically generated based on user input, and the position of the break-even line is calculated based on these labels. However, I'm encountering an issue where the line only renders correctly when it's drawn on the key of the labels array.

**Code Snippet:**

```
const breakEvenLine = {
    type: 'line',
    scaleID: 'x',
    value: minimalIncome,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'black',
    label: {
        content: 'TEST',
        display: true
    }
};
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

- I've verified that minimalIncome is correctly calculated and corresponds to a valid x-axis value.
- I've experimented with different scaleID values to ensure I'm targeting the correct axis.
- I've looked into the documentation (assuming Chart.js or a similar library) for any potential misconfigurations with the line type or the way it's supposed to be added to the chart.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a specific configuration or property I'm missing that enables the line to be drawn based on the value rather than the key of the labels array?
2. Could this issue be related to how I'm updating the chart or the dataset after user input changes?

**Additional Context:**

I'm using Chart.js (latest) for rendering the chart.
The chart updates dynamically as the user inputs data, and the break-even point is recalculated each time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It feels like cheating, but by implementing the if statement:

```
for (let omzet = 0; omzet <= jaarlijkseOmzet; omzet += 2000) {
  oorspronkelijkeOmzetBereik.push(omzet);
  const nieuweOmzet = omzet * 1.60;
  const extraWinst = nieuweOmzet - omzet - investering - extraKosten;
  if (extraWinst >= 0 && breakEvenPunt === 0) {
    breakEvenPunt = omzet;
  }
  extraWinstBerekening.push(extraWinst);
}
```

and:

```
breakEvenPunt = oorspronkelijkeOmzetBereik.findIndex(omzet => omzet >= breakEvenPunt);
```

I found the index to bind to the xMin and xMax:

```
const breakEvenLine = {
  type: 'line',
  xMin: breakEvenPunt,
  xMax: breakEvenPunt,
  borderWidth: 3,
  borderColor: 'black',
  label: {
    content: 'Minimale oorspronkelijke omzet nodig',
    display: true
  }
};
```

I want this question to stay open, because I'm curious to the solution or maybe I'm just not understanding graphs right.

For some reason my "`" to close codes don't work.